# mod_pagespeed doesn't work consistently as I expect

Tags: apache, pagespeed, mod-pagespeed

I have a weird behavioral problem on the mod_pagespeed apache module.

Let's say I see the following part in the HTML.

```html
<link rel=icon type="image/png" sizes=512x512 href=android-chrome-512x512.png>
```

This is the normal output and this is what I expect to see. However, sometimes, when I reload the page/source code page randomly on Chrome, it shows something like:

```html
<link rel=icon type="image/png" sizes=512x512 href=android-chrome-512x512.png.pagespeed.ce.wrFtBi64jT.png>
```

I don't understand 1. why mod_pagespeed is using the image optimization filters without my permission, 2. why this behavior is so inconsistent and random.

Note: my .htaccess

```ini
<IfModule pagespeed_module>
  ModPagespeed on
  ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_css
  ModPagespeedEnableFilters trim_urls
  ModPagespeedJpegQualityForSaveData 50
  ModPagespeedEnableFilters remove_quotes
  ModPagespeedEnableFilters insert_dns_prefetch
  ModPagespeedEnableFilters elide_attributes
  ModPagespeedEnableFilters collapse_whitespace,remove_comments
</IfModule>
```

PS.

I found the same weird behavior on not only images but on CSS files, JS files. e.g. when I have /js/a.js, /js/b.js, /js/c.js, sometimes I see /js/a.js, /js/b.js.pagespeed.ce.PU7e2PU56s.js, /js/c.js, and on an other time I see /js/a.js.pagespeed.ce.atkWWxZ9VJ.js, /js/b.js, /js/c.js and so on. Pretty random. What's going on?